# Default spacing around operators in math inline mode

Tags: math-mode, spacing

When writing math expression, the spacing around an operator (like `+` or `=`) seems to be the same in math inline-mode or math block-mode. However, I like the spacing in an expression to be smaller in inline math. I usually use `\!` around operators to reduce the spacing. Is there a way to automatically decrease the spacing for math inline mode only?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}
This is inline mode $c=a+b$ and this is block-mode
\[
  c=a+b
\]
I can decrease the space like this $c\!=\!a\!+\!b$.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this, but your readers will hate you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\medmuskip=2mu plus 1mu minus 2mu
\thickmuskip=3mu plus 3mu

\AtBeginDocument{
  \everydisplay=\expandafter{%
    \the\everydisplay
    \medmuskip=4mu plus 2mu minus 4mu
    \thickmuskip=5mu plus 5mu
  }%
}

\begin{document}

This is inline mode $c=a+b$ and this is block-mode
\[
  c=a+b
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the display environments such as `align` or `gather` and the others defined by `amsmath` will use the “extended” spacing, because they are typeset inside a standard display, so `\everydisplay` is executed before starting them.

Comment: no of course not. Who maintains `amsmath` anyway?